# Access VBA - getting value of current record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a very new user of Access 2016 - I have a form populated by a query, and I want to create a hyperlink out of one of the text boxes. The link should include the combined values of the *workday* and *taskID* fields for the specific record the user clicks on.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the value of the current record. The control source for these columns are the values themselves, retrieved via the query populating the form's record source. The following code creates the link I want, but it returns the same *workday* and *taskID* values every time, regardless of what I click on, and I can't figure out how to make it respect the current record. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub workday_Click()

Dim link As String
Dim workday as String
Dim taskID as string

workday = Format(Me!workday, "yyyy-mm-dd")
taskID = Me!taskID

link = "http://myurl.com/" & workday & "/" & taskID
Application.FollowHyperlink (link)

End Sub
```

**EDIT** - hope this helps explain a little better

The main table driving this has workID (PK), Workday, taskID, StatusID, DateLastUpdated, UpdatedByUserID. The query used for my form selects all from this table and joins in metadata tables for Task, Status and User. There are multiple records with the same workday value and the same taskID, but never the same combination of the two. The form has a few filters in the header, and the bottom section is a datasheet. In the datasheet I have a combo box used to update StatusID, all other fields are disabled and locked. My hyperlink click event is on the Workday field, and is working in that it creates the appropriate URL, it's just populated with the same taskID and workday values, eg even if I click on the row for "2016-07-12" "456", I still return "2016-07-11" & "123"

Here's a simplified version of what the data looks like. My goal is that when the user clicks on a workday, they are taken to a hyperlink made up of both the workday and TaskID of the row clicked on.

```
Workday     TaskID
2016-07-11  123
2016-07-11  456
2016-07-11  789
2016-07-12  123
2016-07-12  456
2016-07-12  789
2016-07-13  123
2016-07-13  456
2016-07-13  789
```

Comment: Are you navigating to next record for next link? If so, the `workday` and `taskID` field must not be bounded or all or very many records share same data. Please post query contents.

Comment: Are the records in a datasheet? Or continuous form? What are you clicking on when you get "the current record"? Can you send a screen shot?

Comment: What does a working (manually typed) url look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I actually solved it - the problem was that since almost all fields were locked and disabled, the current record wasn't technically the row I was clicking on. I set Enabled = Yes for the Workday column, and now it's working as expected.